# CSS specificity: [parent ID] [descendant combinator (space)] [my class] more specific than [my ID]?

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

Is my reasoning wrong is this a valid CSS rule?

Firstly:

1. [My ID] is more specific than [my class].

Secondly:

2. [My ID] is more specific than [parent ID].

But:

3. **[parent ID] [descendant combinator (space)] [my class] more specific than [my ID]?**

[See it for yourself - JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/kahutedotu/1/edit?html,css,output).

This really surprises me because I have never heard of this combination before, not in the [Specificity Wars](https://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html) neither in https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity

Comment: what is parent id? and why is it more specific than my id? if it is a single id then it is the same specificity as my id.  but for that third one, you are putting up 3 selectors against one so it is going to be more specific

Comment: @Pete parent id is the id of parent element, see the example I posted.

Comment: well then parent id has the same specificity as child id - it is one id so they have the same level of specificity (the child just overrides the style of the parent as you are styling it directly so it is not inheriting - which is different to specificity).  Read this: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ it is a good explanation on how specificity is calculated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [My ID] is more specific than [parent ID]

No, a lone ID is a lone ID. What's important in your example is *which* element it is being applied to.

> [parent ID] [descendant combinator (space)] [my class] more specific than [my ID]

Yes, it's valid, and it is more specific. Using the [W3C's](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) *abc* model:

```
#child { // 1, 0, 0 = 100 Specificity }

#parent .foo { // 1, 1, 0 = 110 Specificity }

#parent #child { // 2, 0, 0 = 200 Specificity }

#parent #child.foo { // 2, 1, 0 = 210 Specificity }
```

So, `#parent .foo` will trump `#child`, but `#parent #child` trumps `#parent .foo`

```css
#parent { /* 100 */
  color: blue;
}
#parent .foo { /* 110 */
  color: green;
}
#child { /* 100 */
  color: red;
}
#parent #child { /* 200 */
  color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child" class="foo bar">what color am I?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Got it. I have mixed specificity with inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

> [My ID] is more specific than [parent ID].

No; they're equally specific. An ID is an ID and it will always have the same specificity. But if the two IDs are matching different elements, then specificity is irrelevant in the first place.

Remember that specificity only applies when you have two or more selectors matching the same element.

> **[parent ID] [descendant combinator (space)] [my class] more specific than [my ID]?**

The additional class selector makes the former more specific than the latter.

Note that combinators have no influence on specificity. The complex selector `#id .class`, with a descendant combinator, is equally specific to the compound selector `#id.class`.